Nested Routing in Remix using Remix Flat Folders
I have these routes to show:

/order/product-id
/order/global
/order/local

How do I hide the navigation bar in the /order/product-id.tsx?
I have _layout.tsx that contains the navigation bar.
This is my folder structure
- order+
   _layout.tsx   --->  this contains the navigation bar
   - product-id.tsx
   - global.tsx
   - local.tsx


If you want to opt out of a parent layout, you would typically add the _ suffix. Since you're using hybrid routes, you can't easily add that to the order layout.
To handle this scenario, there's an undocumented way to do this. Simply add the _. prefix to your product-id.tsx route.
_.product-id.tsx (this will add the _ suffix to the parent layout)
https://github.com/kiliman/remix-flat-routes/commit/1a2e3b1cbecba2c83d05242fbd89e8e513294696
